# Red led repeatedly blinks 4 short and 4 long on RPi 3B+ with TinyCore

Tags: boot-issues, led

The red led repeatedly blinks 4 long 4 short and the Pi doesn't boot.
Tested with various power adapters.

When powered up without an SD card the red led is solid.
I'm using an SD card that works fine with an RPi 2 and 3B.

What could be the problem?

Comment: This is a bit light on detail.  It would be nice to know if the Pi boots and such like.

Comment: @joan updated. Any other details?

Comment: check if tinycore supports the 3B+ - last I read, it did not

Comment: Hi, It indicates the power issue on your board. Can you explain the power supply details? Pi needs constant 5V, 2.5A. If there is no load, It can work with less current source but I can't compromise with the voltage. If it drops(Obviously with some tolerance), Red LED starts blinking.

Comment: I would be tempted to flash Raspbian OS Lite to a USB drive and see if it boots from that if you have one that can boot a Pi.  Some USB adapters will only boot the OS if you have bootcode.bin on the SD - not what you want if its the SD card gone pop...

Comment: @JaromandaX piCore-11.0 supports all boards inc the 4 - not 100% on the compute boards though - not tried it. A few 'quirks' are documented http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php/topic,23935.0.html

Comment: amazing how things change after TWO YEARS @Andyroo

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_blinking) a blinking *red* LED indicates power problems but does not specify any pattern to the blinking.

If it were the *green* LED flashing then [further down](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) on the same article has some more suggestions that fit better with your description of four flashes cycling.

Answer (score 0):

RED LED is controlled by "STATUS_LED_R" signal.
Only solid knowledge available to public is that RED LED is a power indicator and turns off when RPi supply voltage goes bellow 5V with some tolerance. 
Even with "reduced schematic" it really does not matter from where this STATUS signal comes from, what is important is its absence indicating  power problem **with your SD CONNECTOR**, long time known "problem" - they do go bad! 
If your SD works elsewhere , and your RPi stays on without it  - what else is there  which is common? Try different  SD to verify my guess.